# Not declared in scope. Multiple errors

Tags: c++, scope, swap, eof

For some reason, I keep getting a scope error. I continue to get multiple scope errors as well as.

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<fstream.h>
#include<assert.h>

 void ScanInFile(int ScanInValues[], int *total)
{
   int i=0;

   while(!cin>>&ScanInValues[i].eof()){
      i++;
      *total = i;
   }

}

void SortFile(int DataSetValues[], int TotalValues)
{
   int i, j, temp;

   for(i = 0; i < (TotalValues - 1); i++){
      for(j=0; j < TotalValues - i -1; j++){

      if(DataSetValues[j] > DataSetValues[j+1]){
         temp = DataSetValues[j];
         DataSetValues[j] = DataSetValues[j+1];
         DataSetValues[j+1] = temp;
         }
      }
   }

}

int main(void)
{
   int i, AmountOfValues=0;
   int values[100]={ 0 };

 ScanInFile(values, &AmountOfValues);

 SortFile(values, AmountOfValues);

  for(i=0; i < AmountOfValues; i++){
  cout<<values[i];

   }
   cout<<endl;
   return 0;
}
```

For some reason G++ wont compile the program. I continue to get an error for saying endl and cout, and eof are not not in the scope. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Woah! I don't know what you think `!cin >> &ScanInValues[i].eof()` does but it definitely doesn't do what you want! o_0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those objects are declared inside `std` namespace. Either you prepend `std::` before them(`std::cout << ...`) or add `using namespace std;` at the beginning of your cpp file.

After you fix your eof error, you also want to check for out of bound access on your array since you never check size before writing.

Comment: Just edited to add a little something about array size.

Comment: What do you mean check my out of bond access on my array?

Comment: You're adding values in the array as long as user does not end input. After 100 values, you'll continue writing after the array and much likely get a crash at some point.

Comment: Oh I gotcha, thanks! luckily im only reading a dataset with values under 100.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Eric has said, there are more problems in your code that have yet to be pointed out. There's one in your `ScanInFile` function in which you wrote this line:

```
while (!cin >> &ScanInValues[i].eof())
```

This line will compile, but it will do something very different than what you expect. I'm assuming you're performing extraction on this line but want to execute these extractions while the end-of-file has not been reached. There's no need for the `.eof()` as the stream will analyse the stream state itself through an implicit conversion to boolean. This is done as:

```
while (cin >> ScanInValues[i])
```

I don't want to overcompilcate my explanation, but I just want to stress that this is the *preferred* way of performing extraction. Using `!eof()` as a condition for extraction is almost always the wrong way to go.

Comment: OH! While researching eof to scan in files until the file is ended, multiple people have used .eof() just like in C. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @user3078582 Many people use `.eof()` as the condition but they are misinformed as to the reliability of said function. You're supposed to perform the extraction *before* checking the stream state, doing otherwise can cause deadly problems.